# Trim url to last subfolder in VB

Tags: vb.net, string, url, directory, trim

I have a string in VB:
url = "http://example.com/aa/bb/cc.html"

I want to trim this url to the last sub-folder so it becomes: 
url = "http://example.com/aa/bb"

I need everything after the last "/" to be removed.
I am thinking of using the string.lastindexof("/") method but don't know how to continue from there.

Answer (score 2):

use a combination of Substring and Lastindex of. Like this:

```
url.substring(0,url.lastindexof("/"))
```

might be that you need to substract 1 from the lastindexof("/") value, i always forget it^^

Answer (score 2):

When working with an URL, consider using the `Uri` class. Then handling such cases become easy.

Create a `Uri` instance:

```
Dim url = new Uri("http://example.com/aa/bb/cc.html")
```

Then you can either do

```
Dim result = url.AbsoluteUri.Remove(url.AbsoluteUri.Length - url.Segments.Last().Length)
```

or something like

```
Dim result = new Uri(url, ".").AbsoluteUri
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.Remove() to remove the unwanted part of the string:

```
Dim temp As String = "http://example.com/aa/bb/cc.html"
Dim index As String = temp.LastIndexOf("/"c)
Dim ret As String = temp.Remove(index, temp.Length - index)
```